# I can't put icons on Ubuntu 16.04 gnome-fallback desktop

Tags: gnome, permissions, 16.04, gnome-classic, gsettings

I am running Ubuntu  16.04 Gnome, but using Gnome-fallback (metacity). I can't drag and drop icons from the application pull-down menu, but when I copied my backup from my external hard drive, which had the old icons from Ubuntu 14.04 Gnome (again, using Gnome-fallback), the icons (other than mounted volumes, home, network servers, and trash) that had been there in 14.04 suddenly appeared. I know there is a "gsettings" command that can rectify this situation, but I'll be damned if I can remember the content or syntax. Also, I used chown to give myself ownership of the Desktop directory, but it made no difference. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Open Terminal and type this text for each icon you want visible on the desktop, if you're using gnome.

For home folder:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.desktop home-icon-visible true
```

For computer icon:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.desktop computer-icon-visible true
```

For volume icons:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.desktop volumes-visible true
```

Comment: You can also use the same line for trash and network icons.